# Copy data from excel to outlook using powershell

Tags: powershell

I tried the following code but it pastes some garbage text while copying data from excel to outlook. Using powershell.
Code used:

```
$body=""
get-content "C:\Users\smi00019\Desktop\AO\Book1.xlsx" | foreach{$body+="$_`n"}
```

Excel data:

```
Name    Place   Animal
ABC     Mumbai  Dog
XYZ     Pune    Cat
```

I am trying to copy above data range A1:c3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Excel data with Powershell and write to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615364/read-excel-data-with-powershell-and-write-to-a-variable)

Comment: you are not reading "garbage data", you are trying to get what's in the file, which is more than simply the values in the cells.

Comment: You need the link Pac0 posted or save the file as csv rather than xlsx and use Import-Csv to bring the data into Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

`Get-Content` is for use with text-based files. Excel files are not text based and contain other elements (formatting, formulas, macros, graphs etc)

I would recommend using the [PSExcel](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) Module as it contains the `Import-XLSX` function which makes working with Excel files very easy.

`Import-XLSX` works like `Import-CSV`, and generates an 'array' object from the file.

Excel:

[image]

```
$Imported = Import-XLSX -Path C:\Temp\Demo.xlsx -Header samaccountname, EID, Date
```

PS Object:

[image]

---

You can then use `Select-Object` to get the `Property` (column names) you want and that you only the `First` two entries (rows).

```
$Imported | Select-Object -Property Column1,Column1,Column1 -First 2
```