# batch or vb script to read URL from excel file and download URL attached file to specified location or directory

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, download, automatic-storage

I am looking for a VB script or batch file to read & Execute multiple URLs from an CSV file containing the URL Data in column B & The  mentioned URL directly contains on the downloadable file which need to store at location or directory named on behalf of content stored in Column A.

Column A & Column B could be vice versa.

I was trying same thing with batch file but unable to read CSV file automatically instead able to create simple code as show below but would be no success for daily usage as automatic as always required manual intervention, please help accordingly, also check in Python solution code is available but do not want to use it as required Python installation as do not want to do so too.

```
@echo Off
TITLE Test File Download and Storage
Pause
CD\
d:
cd Test
dir Tes_poc1 [i.e. From column A] 
curl http://www.abcd,com/file1.pdf > file1.pdf [URL Just for example, can't share actual one due to security limitations]
cd Test
dir Tes_poc2 "i.e. From column A" 
curl http://www.abcd,com/file2.pdf > file2.pdf [URL Just for example, can't share actual one due to security limitations]
```

---

***Edit :***

Also tried following VBscript able to download file and create folder but unable to move downloaded file to respective folder:

```
dim objFileSys, objReadFile
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const csFSpec = "1.txt"
Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim goWS : Set goWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim tsIn : Set tsIn = goFS.OpenTextFile(csFSpec)
Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
Dim sLine : sLine = tsIn.ReadLine
goWS.Run """chrome.exe"" """ & sLine & """", 1, True
Loop
tsIn.Close
Set objFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objReadFile = objFileSys.OpenTextFile("D:\Test\2.txt", ForReading)
Do until objReadFile.AtEndOfStream = True
objFileSys.CreateFolder(objReadFile.ReadLine)
Loop
objReadFile.Close
Set objReadFile = Nothing
Set objFileSys = Nothing
```

Where 1.txt contains list of urls and 2.txt contains list of respective URL folder name to be create

here are few Example URL's you can use as sample.
                                            http://www.iiswc.org/iiswc2009/sample.doc

https://www.scc.kit.edu/downloads/jrg-mb/Abstract_template.doc

https://www.k-state.edu/grad/etdr/template/mastersinstructions.doc

https://www.cdc.gov/polio/stop/doc/stop-cv-format.doc

Comment: Are these download lines work?  The easiset way to read a cell value from excell is with powershell - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615364/read-excel-data-with-powershell-and-write-to-a-variable

Comment: You should provide a sample csv (if neccessary anonimized) otherwise it is a guessing game. `curl.exe`  (included with the latest win 10 update) has a bunch of options: `-o, --output <file> Write to file instead of stdout`

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51082775/edit) and provide us an example structure of your csv file !

Comment: Tes_poc1,http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf
Tes_poc2,https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png "this is perfect example for CSV type"

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the contents of the.csv file like this one in the same folder of your batch file : **Test.csv**

> ```
> Tes_poc1,http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf
> Tes_poc2,https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
> ```

You can do something like this to download files with Certutil command line :

```dos
@echo off
Mode 60,3 & Color A
Title Download files with Certutil command by Hackoo 2018
Set "File=%~dp0Test.csv"
Set "DownloadFolder=%~dp0Test"
if not exist "%DownloadFolder%" MD "%DownloadFolder%"
CD /D "%DownloadFolder%"
@for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%i in ('Type "%File%"') do (
    If not exist "%DownloadFolder%\%%i\" MD "%DownloadFolder%\%%i\"
    cls & echo( & echo       Downloading "%%~nxj"
    Call :Download %%j %DownloadFolder%\%%i\%%~nxj
)
Start "" Explorer "%DownloadFolder%" & Exit
::--------------------------------------------
:Download <Url> <File>
certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f %1 %2 >nul
exit /b
::-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help but facing bit issue with file download, i am able to create folder but unable to download any file from relevant URL, might be we require some sleep time within URL executions and folder creation. also i am unable to execute complete  command without any pause like always asking to "Press any key to continue". The solution you provided seems to be much better then mine, need bit more help with improvement in code, tried my self too but i am not having that much expetise with certutil usage. again thanks for your great help

Comment: also have added one of VB script combined code for the raised query, able to download files and create folder simuntaneously but not able to move each downloaded file to respective folder only or det default download to respective folder. please check my quetion i have update same there

Comment: @mr.cooldeath Without the contents of `1.txt`and `2.txt` we can't make any progress ? the url ends up with `.pdf` or not i mean, did you have a direct link or not ?

Comment: Have updated sample URLs in Question, Thanks for support

Comment: @mr.cooldeath and 2.txt ? How it looks ? give me at least 4 rows from it !

Comment: 1.txt only contains URL information per row type format and 2.txt contains folder name similarly alike to 1.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for this vbscript with a progressbar in bonus !

***Usage : Drag and Drop a text file that contains url per row over this script  to be downloaded***

Or

**Usage in command line :** ***Cscript //nologo "ThisVbsFile" "Path\TextFile.txt"***

```
Option Explicit
Const Copyright =" (C) by Hackoo 2018"
Dim Title,InputFile,objFSO,objStream,dic,URL,FileName,PathScript
Dim BaseName,Save2File,Folder,k,WaitingMsg,ws,Temp,oExec,HH
Title = "Download From File"
If WSH.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Usage : Drag and Drop a text file that contains url per row over " &_
    "this script "& DblQuote(WSH.Scriptname) & " to be downloaded "& vbCrlf &_
    "OR " & vbCrlf &_
    "Usage in command line : "& vbCrlf &_
    "Cscript //nologo "& DblQuote(WSH.Scriptname) & " " & DblQuote("Path\TextFile.txt"),_
    vbExclamation,Title & Copyright
    Wscript.Quit(1) 
End If
InputFile = Wscript.Arguments(0)
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile (InputFile, 1)
set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
Do while not objStream.AtEndOfStream
   URL = objStream.ReadLine
   If URL <> "" Then
   FileName = GetFileNamefromDirectLink(URL)
   PathScript = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName) 'Path of this Vbscript
   BaseName = GetFilenameWithoutExtension(FileName)
   Folder = PathScript & "\" & BaseName
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(Folder) Then 
        objFSO.CreateFolder(Folder)
    End If
   dic.Add URL,Folder & "\" & FileName
   End If
Loop

For Each URL in dic
    Save2File = dic(URL)
    WaitingMsg = "Please wait ... The download of : <font color=Yellow>"& DblQuote(Save2File) & "</font> is in progress ..."
    Call CreateProgressBar(Title,WaitingMsg)'Creation of Waiting Bar
    Call LaunchProgressBar() 'Launch of the Waiting Bar
    Call Download(URL,Save2File)
    pause(1)
    Call CloseProgressBar()
Next

Set HH = CreateObject("Internet.HHCtrl")
HH.TextPopup " Download is finished ! ", "Tahoma,32", 10,10,10,500
Pause(3)
Wscript.Quit(0)
'------------------------------------------------
Sub Download(URL,Save2File)
    Dim File,Line,BS,ws
    On Error Resume Next
    Set File = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    File.Open "GET",URL, False
    File.Send()
    If err.number <> 0 then
        Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error Getting File"
        Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & vbcrlf &_
        err.description
        Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source 
        MsgBox Line,vbCritical,"Error getting file"
        Err.clear
        wscript.quit
    End If
    If File.Status = 200 Then ' File exists and it is ready to be downloaded
        Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
        BS.type = 1
        BS.open
        BS.Write File.ResponseBody
        BS.SaveToFile Save2File, 2
    ElseIf File.Status = 404 Then
        MsgBox "File Not found : " & File.Status,vbCritical,"Error File Not Found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Unknown Error : " & File.Status,vbCritical,"Error getting file"
    End If
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------
Function GetFileNamefromDirectLink(URL)
    Dim ArrFile,FileName
    ArrFile = Split(URL,"/")
    FileName = ArrFile(UBound(ArrFile))
    GetFileNamefromDirectLink = FileName
End Function
'------------------------------------------------
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'------------------------------------------------
Function GetFilenameWithoutExtension(FileName)
    Dim Result, i
    Result = FileName
    i = InStrRev(FileName, ".")
    If ( i > 0 ) Then
        Result = Mid(FileName, 1, i - 1)
    End If
    GetFilenameWithoutExtension = Result
End Function
'------------------------------------------------
Sub CreateProgressBar(Title,WaitingMsg)
    Dim ws,fso,f,f2,ts,ts2,Ligne,i,fread,LireTout,NbLigneTotal,Temp,PathOutPutHTML,fhta,oExec
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    PathOutPutHTML = Temp & "\Barre.hta"
    Set fhta = fso.OpenTextFile(PathOutPutHTML,2,True)
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<Title>  " & Title & Copyright & "</Title>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTA:APPLICATION"
    fhta.WriteLine "ICON = ""magnify.exe"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "BORDER=""THIN"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "INNERBORDER=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MAXIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MINIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SCROLL=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SYSMENU=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SELECTION=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SINGLEINSTANCE=""YES"">"
    fhta.WriteLine "</HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<BODY text=""white""><CENTER>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<marquee DIRECTION=""LEFT"" SCROLLAMOUNT=""3"" BEHAVIOR=ALTERNATE><font face=""Comic sans MS"">" & WaitingMsg &"</font></marquee>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<img src=""data:image/gif;base64,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"" />"
    fhta.WriteLine "</CENTER></BODY></HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""VBScript""> "
    fhta.WriteLine "Set ws = CreateObject(""wscript.Shell"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(""%Temp%"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Sub window_onload()"
    fhta.WriteLine "    CenterWindow 575,100"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Self.document.bgColor = ""DarkOrange"" "
    fhta.WriteLine " End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine " Sub CenterWindow(x,y)"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Dim iLeft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.resizeTo x,y"
    fhta.WriteLine "    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.moveTo ileft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine "</script>"
    fhta.close
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------
Sub LaunchProgressBar()
    Set oExec = Ws.Exec("mshta.exe " & Temp & "\Barre.hta")
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------
Sub CloseProgressBar()
    oExec.Terminate
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'------------------------------------------------
Sub Pause(Secs)    
    Wscript.Sleep(Secs * 1000)    
End Sub  
'------------------------------------------------
```